# Is __init__.py run everytime I import anything from that module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a module called `core`, which contains a number of python files.

If I do:

```
from core.curve import Curve
```

Does `__init__.py` get called? Can I move import statements that apply to all core files into `__init__.py` to save repeating myself? What **should** go into `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 3):

> I've got a module called core, which contains a number of python files.

if it contains python files, it's not a module, it's a directory containing python files - and eventually a package if it contains an `__init__.py` file.

> If I do: `from core.curve import Curve` does `__init__.py` get called?

It's never "called" - it's not a function  - but it gets loaded the first time the package or one of it's submodules gets imported in a process. It's then stored in `sys.modules` and subsequent imports will find it there.

> Can I move import statements that apply to all core files into **init**.py to save repeating myself?

Nope. namespaces are per-module, not per-package. And it would be a very bad idea anyway, what you name "repeating yourself" is, in this case, a real helper when it comes to maintaining your code (explicit imports means you know without ambiguity which symbol comes from which module).

> What should go into **init**.py?

Technically you can actually put whatever you want in your `__init__.py` files, but most often than not they are just empty. A couple known uses case are [using it as a facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) for the package's submodules,  selecting a concrete implementation for a common API based on thye current platform or some environment variable etc...

Oh and yes: it's also a good place to add some meta informations about your package (version, author etc).

Answer (score 1):

> Is __init__.py run everytime I import anything from that module?

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) in most cases **yes**, it is.

Comment: Where have you seen in the linked doc that the `__init__.py` would get loaded on each and any import ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add all your functions that you want to use in your directory

```
- core
  - __init__.py
```

in this `__init__.py` add your class and function references like

```
from .curve import Curve 
from .some import SomethingElse
```

and where you want to User your class just refer it like

```
from core import Curve
```